# How to match alternatives with python regex

Tags: python, regex, string

given string 1:

'''TOM
likes to go swimming
MARY 
loves to go to the playground
JANE
likes going shopping'''

I want to capture the text between only 2 names. Either Tom and Mary or Tom and Jane. If Mary appears before Jane, I would like to capture the text between Tom and Mary. However, if Jane appears first, I would like to capture the text between Tom and Jane.

I have written the following code:

```
text = re.compile(r'''(
            TOM\s*
            ([\w\W]+)\s*
            JANE|MARY
            )''', re.VERBOSE)

text_out = text.search(string).group(1)
```

However, this code would give me the text between Tom and Jane, even though Mary appears first. I understand that this is because the pipe function reads from left to right and therefore will match Jane first. Is there a way to code this such that it depends on who appears first in the text?

for example, in string2:
"'''TOM
likes to go swimming
JANE
likes going shopping
MARY 
loves to go to the playground
'''

I would like to capture the text between Tom and Jane for string2.

Comment: you understand wrong. neither is there a "pipe function", nor has it anything to do with the order of JANE and MARY in the regex. question: why have you already decided to use regex, even though you don't know how they work or whether they can solve your problem?

Comment: Your remark about the pipe function doesn't really make sense. You want to match JANE or MARY, whichever occurs first. Regex can do this fine by demanding that the match between TOM and either of those names is as small as possible. You just need to bracket (JANE|MARY) properly so that it is parsed as a single disjunction.

Comment: @Denziloe won't work either, since regex are greedy by default.

Comment: I explicitly covered that.

Comment: Basically, you need to read up on regex and/or play with one of the many online regex tools. And replace the thing you have with `([\w\W]+?)`

Comment: You need a lazy quantifier  See previous comment.

Comment: What is `[\w\W]` supposed to match anyway?

Comment: @hop Thanks for your lecture, I am working on improving!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to fix your alternation, it must be enclosed with a non-capturing group `(?:JANE|MARY)`, and use a lazy quantifier with `[\w\W]` (that I would replace with `.*` and use `re.DOTALL` modifier to make the dot to also match line breaks):

```
(?s)TOM\s*(.+?)\s*(?:JANE|MARY)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0XUEps/1)

Without the `(?:...|...)`, your regex matched `Tom`, then any 1+ chars as many as possible (that is, the regex grabbed the whole string, and then backtracked to match the last occurrence of the subsequent subpattern, `JANE`) and `JANE`, or `MARY` substring. Now, the fixed regex matches:

- `(?s)` - DOTALL  inline modifier
- `TOM` - a literal char sequence
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.+?)` - Group 1 (capturing): any 1+ chars, as **few** as possible, up to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns....
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:JANE|MARY)` - either `JANE` or `MARY` substring.

Comment: Thank you so much wiktor!! Really appreciate your help!